# Putting form into namespace causes MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

I created a form which worked just fine. Then I moved the form to the namespace Global.My.NameSpace by adding a namespace statement to the vb and designer.vb file (so everything is still in the same project, but in different namespaces). After that I got the MissingManifestResourceException at runtime complaining that form's resources should be properly embedded into the root namespace of my application.

I checked several solutions here at SO like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it), but nothing worked.

Any idea what to do to solve the problem?

Sascha

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER modify VS-generated files** (*.Designer.vb). It will cause lot of problems.

Comment: I know that this is usually a bad idea, but I don't know how to move a form into a namespace other than modifying the designer file (see for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943813/342594) Moving the form to a different assembly is not an option.So if you don't have any suggestions how to accomplish my goal, your comment is (sorry to say) no help. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I tried to create new Windows Forms application and inside Form1.vb, moved class Form1 to namespace Views. Everything was working fine without need to modify anything else. Problem will be somewhere else.

Comment: Did you change the resources of the form (e.g. changed the icon)?